# Zip dynamic number of observables

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I have a list of observables. The size of it is dynamic. Each observable represents an api call made via Retrofit. So, I need to zip all those calls in order to return a list of responses of the same type.

Here's a look of what I've tried:

```
//The method that perfoms the api call
private fun iterateObservable(params: AssignSeatStatusResponse): List<Observable<SeatSelectionResponse>> {
        val seatsMatrix = mutableListOf<Observable<SeatSelectionResponse>>()
        params.seatJourneys.forEach { seatJourneysItem ->
            seatJourneysItem.seatSegments.forEach { seatSegmentsItem ->
                seatsMatrix.add(
                    this.getSeatMapFromServiceUseCase.createObservable(buildSeatSelectionRequest(seatSegmentsItem))
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                )
            }
        }

        return seatsMatrix

//The method I need to return the list of observables
override fun createObservable(params: AssignSeatStatusResponse): Observable<List<SeatSelectionResponse>> {
        return Observable.zip(iterateObservable(params), FuncN {

        })
    }
```

My problem is the zip displaying an error, saying that *none of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.*

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be apprecciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like this:

```
Observable.zip(iterateObservable) { items ->
    // zip them in some way
}
```

`items` will contain the emission of all `Observable`s in `iterableObservable`

Comment: But this way, we get the objects of type Object. My question is if there is a way to specify the type of the object, so I don't need to explicitly cast the object.

Comment: If `iterateObservable` is a `List<Observable<T>>`, `items` will be an `Array<T>`. Why do you say you get `Object`s?